# C 3355 transistor parameters

Tags: rf

I want to join a company.

They asked me to design a TV UHF booster so I chose *C3355*, but could not find its common base parameter in the UHF range.

Your help promotes me, thanks.

Comment: Pick a transistor for which you do have the common-base params. You need to show them that you understand how to perform the design, and then improve the design.

Comment: Yeah, also, they'll ask *you* questions about your design, not us; they're not interested in applicants doing products they will produce as is in their application, they're interested in applicants showing that they can assess their own abilities and present a device that they are able to design themselves, so they will ask enough questions to figure out whether you did this on your own or with external help. If your job is to design RF amplifiers, *maybe this job really isn't for you*, yet, if finding a transistor with proper parameters is hard for you! That's not a terrible thing; be honest!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Infineon and NXP webpages and pick an RF transistor which meets your specs. They usually provide the device S-parameters for different bias points. You may/should use that for your design.

By the way, I think that Renesas phased-out the RF transistors portfolio, so 2SC3355 is likely to be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

A UHF TV booster is rather a *vague substitute* for a spec as this could be a very different choice for a TV antenna pre-amp or a CATV power amp.

The question is designed to see how you problem-solve, logically-think and your *motus operandi* and thus reveal the depth of your experience and wisdom of choices.

All professional designers **work from specs** for **performance (Q), cost($) and schedule (T)** that they **develop for themselves** with the client, whoever that may be.

Clarifying these requirements is always 1st step and NOT AN implementation-specific design unless requested to make your own assumptions.

This could begin with some criteria like I/O signal levels **(e.g. 10 mV dBmV per 80 channels)**, OIP3, OIP2, P1dB, CSO,